# How to set a cluster autoscale setting to seconds instead of minutes for AKS?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to set the cluster autoscaler for my AKS instance. There's one setting I'm specifically interested in, scale-down-delay-after-add. I want to set it to 30 seconds, but the value is invalid. Does anyone know what it should be?

````
az aks update --resource-group xxx --name xxx --cluster-autoscaler-profile scale-down-delay-after-add=30s```
````

Comment: You could try with the declarative method of changing the default value of `scale-down-delay-after-add` as seen in this [documentation](https://www.programmingwithwolfgang.com/automatically-scale-your-aks-cluster/)